# How to know what file I am currently in/or editting, in VSCode Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am trying to make a personal website where all of my things are in, but I can't figure out this one, I want to let the website know what file I am looking at in vs-code, It's the same as the  Discord RichPrecence extensions, but when I try to read their codes, It's just all scrambled

[image]

The extension looks like this ^^^, I just want to know how they did the "Editing [file].js" and "Workspace: [name]"

Comment: where is this image taken, id this a Webview Panel? You can get the name of the workspace from the `Workspace` object, name of editor from `activeEditor` or let VSC search for workspace editor document belongs to `getWorkspaceFolder` you get an URI

Comment: Thank you for your answers but I've got another problem.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72697148/error-installing-vscode-d-ts-error-request-returned-status-code-404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of discord rich presence extension is [open source](https://github.com/leonardssh/vscord) so you can look it up yourself.

Alternatively you can read the [vscode API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api), you are probably looking for something like `activeTextEditor` from which you can get `TextDocument` property which have a `fileName` string property.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the exact file name from `fileName` string

Comment: can you maybe help me? thank you

Comment: Please post what you already tried and why it isn't working and then we can help you