# Error installing vscode.d.ts: Error: Request returned status code: 404

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

I found a forum with this problem and I followed all of their steps but it still doesn't work, please help me, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also when I try to go into `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/vscode/30d9c6cd9483b2cc586687151bcbcd635f373630/src/vs/vscode.d.ts` It also returns `404: not found`

**Error:**

```
> shinomy@1.0.0 postinstall
> node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install

Detected VS Code engine version: ^1.68.1
Found minimal version that qualifies engine range: 1.68.1
Fetching vscode.d.ts from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/vscode/30d9c6cd9483b2cc586687151bcbcd635f373630/src/vs/vscode.d.ts
Error installing vscode.d.ts: Error: Request returned status code: 404
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Shinomy
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-21T07_50_15_855Z-debug-0.log
```

**My package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "shinomy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install"
  },
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.68.1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.68.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
    "mongo": "^0.1.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.3",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^3.0.0",
    "node-mailer": "^0.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "quick.db": "^7.1.3",
    "speakeasy": "^2.0.0",
    "vscode": "^1.1.37"
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do and what id the forum you found and why do you execute `./node_modules/vscode/bin/install`

Answer (score 2):

Read the [NPM page of `vscode`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode)

> This package is deprecated in favor of `@types/vscode` and `vscode-test`. For more information please read: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_splitting-vscode-package-into-typesvscode-and-vscodetest